# Making a sticky post the first post in the loop - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sticky

I would like to get help with a issue I'm having with the WordPress sticky posts function.

I cant figure it out how to make the stick post stick to the beginning of the loop. I have a loop similar to his:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=10&posts_per_page=3');?>  
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

And I would like it to work like this:

- Sticky post
- Ordinary post
- Ordinary post

Instead for:

- Ordinary post
- Sticky post
- Ordinary post

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

I made two queries, in this case I'm not using pagination maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843214/wordpress-loop-problem-multiple-loops-index-php-and-is-paged-causing-duplicate) can help

```
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $args_nonsticky = array(
        'showposts'     => -1,
        'post__not_in' => $sticky
    );
    $args_sticky = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in'  => $sticky
    );

    $the_query_sticky = new WP_Query($args_sticky); 
    $the_query_nonsticky = new WP_Query($args_nonsticky);

    if(!$the_query_sticky->have_posts() && !$the_query_nonsticky->have_posts()){
        //echo '<h1>NO POSTS FOUND</h1>';
    }else{              

    if ( $sticky[0] ) {
    while ($the_query_sticky->have_posts()) : $the_query_sticky->the_post(); 
      //sticky if so...
    endwhile;
    }

    while ($the_query_nonsticky->have_posts()) : $the_query_nonsticky->the_post(); 
        // non sticky
    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: in my default index.php of my "toolbox" theme the order puts the sticky posts on top, but in my own WP_query i couldn't make it

Comment: The taxonomy filters e.g. for categories are broken this way. You could add to the query arguments: 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy, 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => get_queried_object()->term_id ) )

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102346/how-to-display-post-from-current-taxonomy-in-archive-page

Answer (score 2):

I tested this on my Demo site. And the default order should be:
 - sticky
 - ordinary
 - ordinary
The default order is NOT
 - ordinary
 - sticky
 - ordinary

I recommend testing it with other theme's, like twentyten.
From there it is probably basic debugging
check this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts